# Is there a reference to WPF which enables controls being Draggable?

Tags: wpf, forms, draggable

I've got an application in WPF in which I want to make some controls draggable on the canvas. I know there is a Nuget package Control.Draggable for Windows.Forms but it conflicts with my WPF code:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
public partial class MainWindow : Window
 {
 System.Windows.Controls.Button newButton = new System.Windows.Controls.Button();
 ControlExtension.Draggable(newButton, true);
  }
```

Error message underlining newButton:

> Cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Controls.Button' to
>   'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Is there any way to overcome this error and easily apply draggable feature in WPF?

Comment: You may want to check out [dong-wpf-dragdrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop).

Comment: Thank You, @mm8 I downloaded it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out [dong-wpf-dragdrop](https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop). It's an open-source library that makes it easy to implement and use drag-and-drop functionality in WPF.